# How to make app compatiable for iphone 4S and 5?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, compatibility, iphone-5, iphone-4

I am new to UI design, however a client wants an app ready for both iPhone 4s & 5.

I understand the iPhone 5 will create two bars if the image is not long enough. Many people said coding it at @2x will solve the problem. But I'm not sure exactly what that means.

Do I need to design two versions? What happens if I design only for iPhone 5? Will iPhone 4S users see a squished screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, in a couple of months you'll *have* to support the iPhone 5's screen size. Apple have announced that it'll be a requirement soon.

Adding a Default.png of the right size is enough to *enable* an app to support the new screen size but is likely not enough. You'll also need to make sure that all your views resize to fill the screen. There's the old "springs and struts" method and the newer "constraints." There are tutorials you can search for -- Stackoverflow is not a good place for that kind of thing. You'll also need to update any images.

In short, try it in the Simulator and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Would you recommend then, what rog said above, to have two versions of each view? Would this mean, only iOs6 is supported? What I am concerned about is if I restrict all designs to only the iPhone 5 size, many other iPhone users will not be able to use the app. (Since, I'm sure there are many who haven't made the switch over).

Comment: You need two versions of each _image_, one Retina, one "normal" sized. You don't need two _views_ for every screen as long as you tell iOS how to resize each screen. (I'm assuming you're using `UIView`s here and not something like a game.) And yes, you don't want to restrict to only the iPhone 5. Not even sure you _can_.

Answer (score 0):

Using @2x is referring to whether or not the image asset is being displayed on a 'retina' screen.  For example, if you had a 50x50 pixel image, the 'retina' (@2x) version would be 100x100.  This is because 1pt (point) is equal to 2px (pixel) on a retina screen.

There are a variety of ways you can determine is it is an iPhone5 or iPhone4.

In the `viewDidLoad`, you could check the `self.view.frame.size.height` to determine which background image to load based on the height of the screen.  This would require you to have two different versions of the assets (not including @2x versions), i.e. bg_iphone5.png & bg_iphone4.png.

There are other ways to accomplish this, and people have explained it better than I have here - search StackOverflow and you will surely find what you're looking for.

> What happens if I design only for iPhone 5? Will iPhone 4S users see a squished screen?

Don't do this.  Design for both.